# No login and redirection with Python Social Auth, mobile Chrome (PWA or normal)

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I have a problem with login and redirection using python-social-auth. The documentation says I can do using *next* in link:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Facebook</a>
```

It works okay for Firefox and Chrome on desktops. However on mobile phones I have different behavior.

Mobile Firefox is working without problems. On mobile Chrome (PWA mode or normal mode) I cannot login and I am redirected to /accounts/login page without any errors.

> social-auth-core 1.6.0 social-auth-app-django 2.1.0

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: A redirect to `/accounts/login` usually means that there was an error in the process and the user is sent back to whatever value is assigned to `LOGIN_ERROR_URL` (fallback to `LOGIN_URL` if not defined). Anything odd int he server log?

Comment: @omab, I have checked what is happening and the problem was not in social auth but in my PWA application. Some files were cached and not updated what caused wrong redirect to login page in Chrome. Thanks for good app, it is working as expected now!

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the update.